# FaceRecognition: Does all the images per person must be the same count?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I want to know that, is this important to have the same count of images per person (e.g: 10 image/person) to train faces in Eigen/Fisher/LBPH FaceRecognizer? Or it can be different count (person1: 10 images, person2: 20 images, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Eigen/Fisherfaces, the safest answer is that dataset volumes for each class have to be balanced. While lacking just some images for a class may be OK, having a class which has an order of magnitude more images than all the other ones will definetely cause a problem. Tolerable disbalance is individual for every task, I guess.

At the end of the day, each of the mentioned algorithms falls into finding the closest neighbor from the training dataset to query image. Eigen/Fisherfaces are trained on the whole given dataset, calculating vectors at which the dataset images vary the most. Over- or underrepresenting a class would result in a disbalanced model which would work inadequately towards it.

Conversely, LBPH is not trained on the whole dataset. It analyzes each image from the dataset independetly, and compares the query image to each of them separately. Dataset comprehensiveness and representativeness is thus more important here than image count.

OpenCV has [an intro to inner workings](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) of these algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, sir! And one other I want to ask you that, how can we set a good threshold for these algorithms to use to determine between known and unknown faces. If we set the highest value (Double.Max), then the predicted result always is positive, it makes problem to distinguished the known and unknown faces. If you some way, please suggest me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The threshold is most commonly (and most straightforwardly) set empirically. I'd suggest collecting yet another dataset of random unknown faces which you want to be not recognized, and then adjust the threshold (manually or by iterating) so that most of the known faces are recognized and most of the unknown faces are not.

Comment: You mean that I test the recognize the trained faces and untrained faces and see their returned threshold value?

Comment: I mean the following: `for (double thresh = 0; thresh < DBL_MAX; thresh += step) {/*run recognition with this threshold and count false negatives (for known faces dataset) and false positives (for unknown faces)*/ }`. Then select the thresh which causes the least number of false recognitions with your dataset.